# Flask and nginx routing

Tags: nginx, routes, flask, uwsgi

I've configured nginx + uwsgi + flask and now I am struggling with prepending path to my flask defined routes. The basic question is: Is it even possible?

Let's say I have a route `app.route('/login')` and I would like to configure nginx to access this route like from the address `/api/login`.

My current configuration looks like this but it isn't working

```
location = /api { rewrite ^ /api/; }
location /api { try_files $uri @api; }
location @api {
        include            uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass         uwsgicluster;

    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not keep the route logic in your app?  app.route('/api/login')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion is to keep the routing logic within your application:

```
app.route('/api/login')
```

Or implement an 'api' blueprint with a url_prefix of '/api':

**file: api/views.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, abort
from jinja2 import TemplateNotFound

api = Blueprint('api', __name__, url_prefix='/api')

@api.route('/', defaults={'page': 'index'})
@api.route('/<page>')
def show(page):
    if page == 'login':
        # do something
    try:
        return render_template('pages/%s.html' % page)
    except TemplateNotFound:
        abort(404)
```

**file: app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from .api import api

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(api)
```

Comment: I was looking for the less repetitive solution than writing '/api' everywhere. Thanks for the Blueprint idea!